# How to make git changes while not overwriting previous author's name by current author

Tags: git, bitbucket, qt-creator

I want to beautify the whole project and format the code properly, but it will rewrite the current code and make me the author of, like, 50% of code. Our team and me don't want that. So the question is: how do I make changes to repository, while all the authors stay the same? I understand this process as something that probably contains 2 steps: 1) making a commit in a separate branch with a lot of changes, and then 2) reverting me as an author of every line of this commit to previous authors.

Is it even possible? I can't wrap my head around it. Maybe, there is another way? How can I do it better?

We use Bitbucket repository, Qt Creator as IDE and Artistic Style as a beautifier.

Any help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
```

These variables can be used to forge the name, the email, the date of author and committer on `git commit`.

For example:`GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="foo" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="foo@foo.com" git commit -m 'blah'`

`git cherry-pick` or `git rebase` keeps the same author but changes the committer to the current user.name and user.email in git-config.

If you will use cherry-pick and rewrite some code, here's the possible method.

Let's say `old-branch` is A-B-C.

```
git init newbranch
cd newbranch
git init
git remote add origin /foo/bar/.git
git fetch origin old-branch
git checkout --orphan new-branch A
#make some extra changes
git add .
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(git log -1 --pretty=%an A) GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ae A) GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git log -1 --pretty=%cn A) GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ce A) git commit -m $(git log -1 --pretty=%B A)
git cherry-pick -n B
#make some extra changes
git add .
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(git log -1 --pretty=%an B) GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ae B) GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git log -1 --pretty=%cn B) GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ce B) git commit -m $(git log -1 --pretty=%B B)
#make some extra changes
git add .
git cherry-pick -n C
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(git log -1 --pretty=%an C) GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ae C) GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git log -1 --pretty=%cn C) GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ce C) git commit -m $(git log -1 --pretty=%B C)
```

Now we get the beautified `new-branch`.